# Switch audio output device in Debian Squeeze

Tags: ubuntu, audio, debian, gnome, debian-squeeze

If there are multiple audio card in the system (i.e. internal audio and USB), how to switch the output device easily?

The volume applet in Ubuntu (10.04 or 10.10) provide this feature directly, while Debian doesn't have. I think it is because of the version of gnome-volume-control are different.

I checked the version of gnome-volume-control by

```
$ gnome-volume-control --version
```

then got:

```
Ubuntu 10.10: 2.31.6
Ubuntu 10.04: 2.30.0
Debian Squeeze: ** (gnome-volume-control.gstreamer:30422): DEBUG: deleted the custom theme dir
```

How can I update gnome-volume-control in Debian squeeze?

Comment: 'gnome-volume-control' is provided in the package gnome-media. Seems that Ubuntu add some features of 'gstreamer-properties', while it in Debian doesn't have. I find the feature of selecting output device is provided in the routine 'gstreamer-properties', so the problem is kind of solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can install pavucontrol and/or padevchooser.  The former allows to choose the output device. The second one allows you have it in the tray area.

Comment: This is assuming you want pulseaudio on your system. In Debian it's not installed by default.